# text file encoding detect has issue

Tags: vb.net

I am using streamReader to read a text file and then saving content of file into another text file using streamwriter. File which I am trying to read can be in ANSI or UTF-8 format. 
I am facing problem with non english characters. When input file contains Chinese or Japanese language every thing works fine.

But if input file contains characters like ã then output text file show question mark type symbol.

I tried to fix this by using encoding iso-8859-1 for streamreader but now Chinese and Japanese language coming like this ¢ãƒ­ãƒ¼ãƒ»ãƒ¦ãƒ¼ã

Comment: Do the UTF-8 files have a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?

Comment: Unless your file starts with a BOM as as Andrew suggests, there's really no way to detect the encoding.

Comment: @Andew both file shows same BOM